# How to add terminal icon to File Broswer?

Tags: gui, browser, files, icons

Id like to have terminal icon on toolbar and when I click it to have terminal executed with a current path. how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A somewhat different solution that solves your end goal is the package `nautilus-open-terminal` . It adds a *Open in terminal* context menu, so you can right-click in the file browser and get a terminal with the current path. (Image found [here](http://dunithd.wordpress.com/2009/11/07/add-open-terminal-to-gnome-context-menu-in-ubuntu/).)
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Nautilus-elementary might be something you could try. It has an embedded terminal (F7) shown on the image here:

[image]

Install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:am-monkeyd/nautilus-elementary-ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

[More info on OMG Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/03/phew-nautilus-elementary-revived-in-time-for-ubuntu-natty/)